# Move file on server from remote station?

Tags: macos, file-management

On my Mac I connect to a network attached storage. Then I want to move some files from one folder into another. This is really slow, because the file is not really moved but instead copied. So it is downloaded to my machine and then uploaded again onto the server.

How can I perform a move operation directly on the server from my remote work station?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of this question depends on the NAS itself.  Not all NAS's are created the same.  I suspect that the answer is going to be a definitive "no" unfortunately.  Unless you can gain access to the underlying file-system, you're going to be relying on whatever network protocol to do the transfer... which means unfortunately... you must copy to workstation & back to server.

Comment: It is a Synology DiskStation 211j

Comment: Sorry... I suspect you're out of luck.  I believe the 212j has a built-in web-based management app that will allow you to do some file-system operations... (perhaps move as well) that would bypass you having to do the operation locally... but I am not 100% sure on the 211j

Comment: Thanks. The 211j has also a web based file management. It allows to move files, but on the other hand it lacks some other features.